# Java and Excel Workbook alternative

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm pretty new to Java. One thing I miss about .NET though is easy interoperability with Microsoft Office and Excel.

I tried out using Apache's POI to write Excel workbooks and I was pretty happy with it initially. But when I tried to save larger amounts of data (like 10 MB), it started crashing because I didn't have enough memory. I did some research and this is apparently a common problem.

I could use CSV's, but my end users like receiving self-contained workbooks with multiple sheets, not a couple of flat text files.

I am wondering if there is a Java library to interact with OpenOffice spreadsheet documents or something, which Excel can open and my users won't know the difference. Is there such a solution? What can I use?

Answer (score 2):

The [POI Streaming API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) would solve your original problem, i.e. saving large files. Be aware that not all model option (e.g. richtext formatting) are available with SXXSF.

Answer (score 0):

You could try JODConverter?

https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/

Haven't used it myself but it seems popular even if no longer maintained.

**Edit:**

Other possible options:

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/
http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/